# Create twitter like embeddable component using angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter, components

I am very new to angular2 and I am trying to create an independent, standalone angular2 component, which can be embedded into any website. Somewhat similar to publish.twitter.com and twitter tweet embeds.

I dont want to use iframes like twitter does. Is there any way this can be achieved?

Comment: That's the default behavior. You need to bootstrap the component and it needs an element that matches the selector in the existing HTML on the page.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. Can you please elaborate a little bit on this. Also, can I embed this component in a non-angular web app as well?

Answer (score 0):

Every Angular2 application is a component, called to root component or AppComponent, with possible nested components and directives. An Angular2 application is such a component added to a page.

You can specify a selector for the root component and when the component is bootstrapped it will be attached to the first element on the page that matches that selector. If such a root component doesn't take the whole pages space, you get what you want. 
There is nothing special to this, except that usually an Angular2 applications root component is built so that it takes the whole page, but there is no necessity to do so.

Comment: Yeah that sounds great.  But what I want is for the user to click a button on my component which would generate some code that the user can the copy to embed my component in their website. I want do do two things: 

1. Add the component to my own website, which is not angular. But I might be able to get away with that by adding angular to the application.

2. Second thing is the twitter embed like behaviour, where user should be able to click on button and generate some HTML code that they can then include in their website to display my component. 

Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: You build an Angular2 application to get a deployable. Strip the index.html and provide just the part that is specific to this Angular2 application. This is what you provide to your user to embed it on his site.